# Yii2 Adding new console controller

Tags: php, controller, yii2

Why `yii2` throw exception, when I try use console controller? Code:

```
<?php

namespace app\commands;

use yii\console\Controller;
class Hashtag extends Controller
{


    public function actionIndex($search = 'test')
    {
      echo $search;
    }
}
```

Controller located in: app\commands\HashtagController
When using terminal: `php yii hashtag`

```
Exception 'yii\base\UnknownClassException' with message 'Unable to find 'app\commands\HashtagController' in file: /var/www/html/yiitask/yii2/commands/HashtagController.php. Namespace missing?'

in /var/www/html/yiitask/yii2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php:291
```

Other controller in this folder that was created before, working well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your namespace is wrong set the namespace for console controller properly eg: (depend where you have you console controller directory)

```
  namespace app\console\controllers;
```

then could be is missing controller

```
class HashtagController extends Controller
{
```

instead of

```
class Hashtag extends Controller
{
```

Comment: Default HelloController use `namespace app\commands` and my other controller too. And it`s working. Located in same folder. 'controllerNamespace' => 'app\commands', in app\config\console.php

Comment: Don't worry the intelligent mistake are very rare